# HTML,PHP,Javascript Save to .txt File

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

Is it possible to save to a .txt file all the generated or the inputted text on the text area? I just want to add a Save button besides the submit button or at the bottom and just save it directly to a .txt file. Thanks

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<body>


<form id="myForm">
Name: <br><input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name" size="40"/><br/>
Phone: <br><input type="text" name="Phone No" placeholder="Phone Number"/><br/>
Callback: <br><input type="text" name="Callback No" placeholder="Callback Number"/><br/>
CID: <br><input type="text" name="CID" placeholder="CID No" /><br/>  
Status OK: <br><select name="Status" placeholder="Status"><option>Yes<option>No</select><br/>
INBOUND: <br><select name="INBOUND" placeholder="INBOUND"><option>Yes<option>No</select><br/>
<button type="button" onclick="ShowText();">Submit</button>
</form>
<p>Result:</p>
<p><textarea cols=40 rows=7 id="show" onClick='selectText(this);'></textarea></p>

    <script>
    function ShowText(){
        // find each input field inside the 'myForm' form:
        var inputs = myForm.querySelectorAll('input,select');
        // declare 'box' variable (textarea element):
        var box = document.getElementById('show');
        // clear the 'box':
        box.value = '';
        // loop through the input elements:
        for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
            // append 'name' and 'value' to the 'box':
            box.value += inputs[i].name + ': '+inputs[i].value+'\n';
        }
    }M
    function selectText(textField) 
      {
        textField.focus();
        textField.select();
      }
    </script>

<textarea rows="9" cols="40">
Issue:



Steps:
</textarea>

</body></html>
```

Comment: please rewrite your question. i don't understand even a tiny bit. put yourself as someone who reads this please

Comment: Its kinda simple, i just want to add a save button on which the texts on the text area will be saved on a .txt file with the same folder of the .htm which is specifically the code the i write above.

Comment: using php to save to your server?

Comment: Txt fie on client side or on server side? if server side - where' s related php-code? We should write it for you?

Comment: @u_mulder Hello, i dont knpw if its client side or server side because its im gonna use it for Windows7 or winxp so just the same folder with the .htm file which is the code i posted above. is it possible?

Comment: @DanielCheung just save to the same folder with the .htm file which i posted above. on Windows 7/XP

Comment: @user2910182 I'm not being mean, but you are lacking in web development knowledge. If you don't know the differences between **server-side** and **client-side**, I can't help you. No one can on StackOverflow. The only way for you is to describe your question extra thoroughly in your side of thinking.

Comment: Locally this can only be done with *elevated permissions* in Chrome, Firefox or the use of *ActiveX* in IE (which scares users). With PHP you can process the file on your server and serve it as a download.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use fopen.
if your text from yout post form example : `$_POST['nameoftextarea']` you can add on variable. Maybe like this

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = $_POST['nameoftextarea'];
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

try to explore with the path of your text result too.
here some other example i found to make txt file on php [create txt file using php](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp)

CMIWW

Comment: How can i add the save button? Could you copy my code bro and just create it for me im really not good at php. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Server Side**

Use the following code for server side:

```
$text = $_POST["textarea_name"] //Needs to correspond with the name in the HTML
file_put_contents("myFile.txt", $text); //Change the file path to your needs
```

For more info look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Simple as that. Remember to change your form tag like so (obviously change the action link):

```
<form id="myForm" action="/link/to/process/form" method="POST">
```

and change the name of the text area like so:

```
<textarea cols=40 rows=7 id="show" onClick='selectText(this);' name="textarea_name"></textarea>
```

You'll also need to add a Save button to the form.

```
<button type="submit">Save</button>
```

**Client Side**

For client side check this out:
http://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/
and 
http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side

Those links also tell you how to save data other than text, but I assume your only interested on the text bit.

Comment: Correct im just interested to a .txt file by the way im just gonna save it to the same folder with windows7. I mean im not really good at php can you copy my code and create it for me i'll figure out the rest. Thanks!

Comment: Do i need to create a .php file for this one?i dont get the part of link/too/process/form.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp or look up on other tutroials on PHP forms

Comment: and yes you do need to create another php file and that link is to that file. You can potentially use the same file, but you need to check whether POST data been sent using "isset". I don't think you done a lot of form processing before so please look up on some tutorials on PHP forms.

Comment: Uhm unfortunately i can't make it work when i hit on save its not doing anything already checked the tags. uhm and other stuff that you advised.

Comment: Post the code that you tried. I don't know exactly what part is not working as I don't know what you tried. Was there an error? Did you code it wrong? Try just running file_put_contents("myFile.txt", "Hello World"); on its own to see if that works. If that dosen't then its an permission error

Comment: To be honest, i think i don't know what im doing all i know is copy paste. and just to remind you im using windows 7 i mean its not a server or something. i just want to be saved on C:/ or something. :(

Comment: Yeah I understand that, but your not going to get a solution through just copy and paste without understanding what your doing (well unless I'm doing it for you). Also it dosen't matter if your using a online server or not. As long as you can run PHP this would work. If you want to learn how to do this you need to learn some basic PHP and PHP forms. w3 schools your friend here